# Trying to mount an external hard drive

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have an external hard drive which I plug in.  When I go to disk utility it says it's there but I can't mount it in order to copy or move files from it.  ??  Haven't tried anything in the terminal yet, as I'm not sure where to go with that.  When I type in `sudo blkid`
to list the file systems, here is what comes up

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="37816aba-85b5-476a-aedf-a1cd3f0db76b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="a35c094d-e6eb-4b6d-a63a-8303ae2f567f" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb5: UUID="58dea4d5-89e7-4e28-838f-8d26598a226b" TYPE="swap"
```

I only have this one computer so I am not sure whether it works on other PC's/os's.  The partition type is Linux(0x83)  When I look at it in the disk utility, it says the device is /dev/sdb1. I can't even check filesystem.

I tried mounting it manually, `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external` and it comes up with this.  `mount: you must specify the filesystem type.

Comment: What is the error when you try to mount it?

Comment: Yes! What is the error appearing when you try to mount/click on the drive?? and what is the file format it contains? (Optional: Does it work with other PC's/OS's)??

Comment: Sorry, here's some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) and you should be good to go!